# Calling AWS API Gateway, issue with GET calls

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I am calling below AWS Gateway API from java console application. In postman, it works perfectly with AWS signatures.

GET https://api.valorebooks.com/bid?isbns=["9780026840019"]

I am using AWS SDK and this library.
https://github.com/rpgreen/apigateway-generic-java-sdk

Console app is passing parameter isbns but API is throwing HTTP:400

Source API: https://valorebooks.github.io/api/source/bid/

Comment: it's better if you can add some more information (any custom headers used etc) on the two approaches and the responses perhaps.

Comment: Add some code snippets as well

Comment: @Kamran Qadir You have not shared what you have done so far.

Comment: 400 is a client error.  It's most likely that you are not supplying the query params correctly

Answer (score 0):

Converted parameters to json string and posted that string as parameter to query string

```
Map<String, String> parameters = new LinkedHashMap<>();
List<String> productsIsbs = Arrays.asList(request.getProducts())
                    .stream().map(x -> x.getIsbn()).collect(Collectors.toList());
String params = new Gson().toJson(productsIsbs).replace("\"", "\'");
parameters.put("isbns", params);

GenericApiGatewayRequest apiGatewayRequest;
        try {

            apiGatewayRequest = new GenericApiGatewayRequestBuilder()
                            .withHeaders(headers)
                            .withHttpMethod(HttpMethodName.GET)
                            .withResourcePath("/bid")
                            .withParameters(parameters)
                            .build();

            GenericApiGatewayApacheResponse response = client.executeGetWithHttpClient(apiGatewayRequest);

            if(response.getHttpResponse().getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                String responseJson = response.getBody();
            }

        } catch (GenericApiGatewayException e) {   // exception thrown for any non-2xx response
            System.out.println(String.format("Client exception:%s - %s", e.getStatusCode(), e.getMessage()));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try a GET like this?

`https://api.valorebooks.com/bid?isbns=9780026840019`

There are different ways to represent list in query params. Your API gateway may not be configured correctly aswell.